# Checkboxes not working

Tags: html, css, checkbox

I'm trying to create a checklist but only the first checkbox is working. When I click on the other ones it checks the first box. Also, I added "text-decoration: line-through;" but it's not showing up in the text. I'm pretty sure I can fix that with HTML though.

http://codepen.io/tyl-er/pen/kXmkqB?editors=0100

Here's my code:

```
    <div class="box">
    <input type='checkbox' name='thing' value='valuable' id="thing"/><label for="thing"></label> get an army
      <br>
    <input type='checkbox' name='thing' value='valuable' id="thing"/><label for="thing"></label> free the slaves
      <br>
    <input type='checkbox' name='thing' value='valuable' id="thing"/><label for="thing"></label> train my dragons
      <br>
    <input type='checkbox' name='thing' value='valuable' id="thing"/><label for="thing"></label> cross the narrow sea
      <br>
    <input type='checkbox' name='thing' value='valuable' id="thing"/><label for="thing"></label> become Queen of Westeros
    </div>

<style>
    input[type=checkbox] {
    display:none;
    }
    input[type=checkbox] + label
    {
    background: #999;
    height: 16px;
    width: 16px;
    display:inline-block;
    padding: 0 0 0 0px;
    }
    input[type=checkbox]:checked + label
    {
    background: #0080FF;
    text-decoration: line-through;
    height: 16px;
    width: 16px;
    display:inline-block;
    padding: 0 0 0 0px;
    }

</style>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The text for each checkbox needs to be wrapped inside an element. You could use the css sibling selector to strike through the text against the ticked checkbox.

```css
input[type=checkbox] {
display:none;
}
input[type=checkbox] + label
{
background: #999;
height: 16px;
width: 16px;
display:inline-block;
padding: 0 0 0 0px;
}
input[type=checkbox]:checked + label
{
background: #0080FF;
text-decoration: line-through;
height: 16px;
width: 16px;
display:inline-block;
padding: 0 0 0 0px;
}
input[type=checkbox]:checked + label + label {
    text-decoration: line-through;
}


label p {
  display: inline block;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
<input type='checkbox' name='thing' value='valuable' id="thing"/><label for="thing"></label> <label>get an army</label>
<br>
<input type='checkbox' name='thing1' value='valuable2' id="thing1"/><label for="thing1"></label> <label>free the slaves</label>
<br>
<input type='checkbox' name='thing2' value='valuable3' id="thing2"/><label for="thing2"></label> <label>train my dragons</label>
<br>
<input type='checkbox' name='thing3' value='valuable4' id="thing3"/><label for="thing3"></label> <label>cross the narrow sea</label>
<br>
<input type='checkbox' name='thing4' value='valuable5' id="thing4"/><label for="thing4"></label> <label>become Queen of Westeros</label>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks that totally fixed it.

Answer (score 2):

Problem is with your id's and 'for' properties in labels.
 This will work:

```
<div class="box">
<input type='checkbox' name='thing' value='valuable' id="thing"/><label for="thing"></label> get an army
<br>
<input type='checkbox' name='thing1' value='valuable2' id="thing1"/><label for="thing1"></label> free the slaves
<br>
<input type='checkbox' name='thing2' value='valuable3' id="thing2"/><label for="thing2"></label> train my dragons
<br>
<input type='checkbox' name='thing3' value='valuable4' id="thing3"/><label for="thing3"></label> cross the narrow sea
<br>
<input type='checkbox' name='thing4' value='valuable5' id="thing4"/><label for="thing4"></label> become Queen of Westeros
</div>
```

Always remember that 'id's must be unique throughout html document.
The problem with your code was that every input had same id and browser just changed state for first 'id'.

Comment: Any ideas on how to get the strike-through to work. I realize that my text needs to be inside the label tags for the CSS to apply, but that messes up the layout of the text.

Comment: It will be easy with jQuery. You cannot change outside elements using css.

Answer (score 0):

They all have the same name and ID, `thing`. You need to name them different, or the system will not know them apart.

Comment: This is not correct, input checkboxes can have the same ID and name and it will still function. The issue must be somewhere else.