# How to Create Different Styles for input[type=checkbox]?

Tags: css, checkbox

This response does an excellent job of showing you how to style checkboxes on a page: [Checkboxes not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39030974/checkboxes-not-working)

…albeit *input[type=checkbox]* applies its styling on *all* checkboxes.

I’d like to incorporate images for two different checkboxes – we’ll say facebook and twitter respectively. As a result I’ll need to style them independently because they both have different images and also different images when clicked upon.

With the code below it works perfectly fine for the first checkbox.

Style:

```
 input[type=checkbox] {
 display:none;
 }

 input[type=checkbox] + label
 {
  background-image:url(facebook_active.png);
 height: 53px;
 width: 77px;
 display:inline-block;
 padding: 0 0 0 0px;
 }
 input[type=checkbox]:checked + label
 {
 background-image:url(facebook_inactive.png);
 height: 53px;
 width: 77px;
 display:inline-block;
 padding: 0 0 0 0px;
 }
```

Checkboxes:

```
 <input type='checkbox' name='facebook'  id="facebook"><label for="facebook"></label> 

 <input type='checkbox' name='twitter' id="twitter"><label for="twitter"></label>
```

My question is how can I style the second checkbox (Twitter) just like I did for the Facebook checkbox. Is there a way to be specific on individual ones so that I can style them independently?

Comment: Did you try selecting it by ID? `input[type=checkbox]#twitter + label` and applied the Twitter image there?

Comment: No need to specify the element and attribute if you already use the id.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Click on the images in the Snippet below to see toggle

```css
input[type=checkbox] {
  display: none;
}
#facebook + label {
  background-image: url("https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRvizk1rdyu1GCcYVDH0rQJtFNwo5lKkICU8Q5byYMAhWslC2uWfw");
  height: 53px;
  width: 77px;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0 0 0 0px;
  background-size: contain;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
#facebook:checked + label {
  background-image: url("https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQTnxDwiDgiIn3IxkbO2d5dzR4F27MtO1JeYmNjJDCZ8JZtzDQmTA");
  height: 53px;
  width: 77px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: contain;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0 0 0 0px;
}
#twitter + label {
  background-image: url("https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcR-I0nSWnXixL0KGa38_32giQZyjT7XPhc78AHCb12nG-jvV7u1SA");
  height: 53px;
  width: 77px;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0 0 0 0px;
  background-size: contain;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
#twitter:checked + label {
  background-image: url("https://encrypted-tbn2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRE0GIa1464BUBgLWNNLtqGRsqkWFSGHOgcBxn_qAO5HJuXEVcvMA");
  height: 53px;
  width: 77px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0 0 0 0px;
}
```

```html
<input type='checkbox' name='facebook' id="facebook">
<label for="facebook"></label>

<input type='checkbox' name='twitter' id="twitter">
<label for="twitter"></label>
```

Comment: You keep repeating the same CSS rules over and over.

Comment: looking at the OP reputation..I did this for a reason....for him to digest and optimize the css codes I have written....

Comment: Now you see that +15?

Comment: You don't answer for OP only. This is just bad code and you even did it on purpose to get 15 points. LOL. I hope one day you will understand the purpose of SO.

Comment: #twitter + label, #facebook + label { 
  height: 53px;
  width: 77px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: contain;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0 0 0 0px;
  
}

Comment: @soma56 you're welcom friend

Answer (score 1):

Use the ids to differentiate the two checkboxes. Btw, this is very *very* basic css.

```css
input[type=checkbox] {
  display: none;
}
input[type=checkbox] + label {
  height: 53px;
  width: 77px;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0;
}

#facebook + label {
  background-image: url(facebook_active.png);
}

#twitter + label {
  background-image: url(twitter_active.png);
}

#facebook:checked + label {
  background-image: url(facebook_inactive.png);
}

#twitter:checked + label {
  background-image: url(twitter_inactive.png);
}
```

```html
<input type='checkbox' name='facebook' id="facebook">
<label for="facebook"></label>

<input type='checkbox' name='twitter' id="twitter">
<label for="twitter"></label>
```